# How to scroll to row added to NSTableView after animation has finished

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation, nstableview

After adding a new row to an NSTableView I'd like to scroll to it.

When that row has been added to the end of table the scroll only scrolls to the row that was previously the last row. I initially thought that I had to wait for the animation to finish, but that hadn't solved my issue. Here's my code:

```
        [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
        [_tableView insertRowsAtIndexes:indexSet withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationEffectGap];
        [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setCompletionHandler:^{

            // Scroll to the first inserted row

            NSUInteger firstIndex = [indexSet firstIndex];
            [_tableView scrollRowToVisible:firstIndex];

        }];
        [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to his problem that I'm happy with:

```
[_tableView insertRowsAtIndexes:indexSet withAnimation:NSTableViewAnimationEffectGap];

[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSUInteger firstIndex = [indexSet firstIndex];
    [_tableView scrollRowToVisible:firstIndex];
}];
```

I'm simply delaying the scroll request until the next run loop.

Comment: I tried using this to scroll to the bottom of a tableview after inserting a row at the end and it just scrolls to the second to last row. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We had problems with this, so we ended up doing the scroll as the other animations happen, to keep the row on-screen. You’d call this code inside your animation grouping where you do the tableView modifications.

The code looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)scrollRowToVisible:(NSInteger)row animate:(BOOL)animate;
{
    LIClipView *const clipView = (id)_sourceListOutlineView.enclosingScrollView.contentView;
    const NSRect finalFrameOfRow = [_sourceListOutlineView rectOfRow:row];
    const NSRect clipViewBounds = clipView.bounds;

    if (NSIsEmptyRect(finalFrameOfRow) || _sourceListOutlineView.numberOfRows <= 1)
        return NO;

    const NSRect finalFrameOfLastRow = [_sourceListOutlineView rectOfRow:(_sourceListOutlineView.numberOfRows - 1)];
    if (NSMaxY(finalFrameOfLastRow) <= NSHeight(clipViewBounds))
        // The source list is shrinking to fully fit in its clip view (though it might still be larger while animating); no scrolling is needed.
        return NO;

    if (NSMinY(finalFrameOfRow) < NSMinY(clipViewBounds)) {
        // Scroll top of clipView up to top of row
        [clipView scrollToPoint:(NSPoint){0, NSMinY(finalFrameOfRow)} animate:animate];
        return YES;
    }

    if (NSMaxY(finalFrameOfRow) > NSMaxY(clipViewBounds)) {
        // Scroll bottom of clipView down to bottom of source, but not such that the top goes off-screen (i.e. repeated calls won't keep scrolling if the row is higher than visibleRect)
        [clipView scrollToPoint:(NSPoint){0, MIN(NSMinY(finalFrameOfRow), NSMaxY(finalFrameOfRow) - NSHeight(clipViewBounds))} animate:animate];
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Hi Wil. It seems to me that the problems stems from the fact that the rows doesn't exist until after the insert has been performed.I've tried delaying my scrollToRow call for 0.1 seconds (using a dispatch_after) and that solves the issue. Feels hacky though. I couldn't easily test your code since scrollToPoint isn't a defined function.

Comment: Oh, we added the animate: parameter to our clipView subclass, that's right. It seems strange you can’t refer to the row immediately after insertion, even if animation is going on, but all this code is pretty new.